# "Replot" a matplotlib inline plot in a IPython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, visualization, scientific-computing

if I work on a `matplotlib` *inline* plot in an ipython notebook like this:

```
figure = plt.figure()
ax = figure.gca(projection="3d")
graph = np.empty([len(thetaYield),3])
for g, tY in zip(graph, thetaYield):
    sample =  HWtoPS(xiYield, rhoYield, tY)
    g[...] = sample[:]
ax.plot(graph[:,0],graph[:,1], graph[:,2])
plt.show()
```

the plot is drawn inline in my notebook as it intended.

Now I want to add to add some data to this plot:

```
principalStress, vectors = eig(sigma)
ax.scatter(principalStress[0], principalStress[1], principalStress[2])
plt.show()
```

no error, but also **no plot is drawn**.

I **expected** to get an "updated" version of my plot with the additional data.

**How can this be done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A: This can be done at a cost of changed `matplotlib` Renderer

Currently, this cannot be done for the `IPython` "inline" graphs, however, if you opt to change a **`Renderer`** part of the `matplotlib` framework, to another one, the limitation of a singleton call of the `.show()` method does not hurt and you can ex post modify the object's content and it gets re-processed by the `Renderer`.

Simply:

**add** a directive ( IPython *magic*) **`%matplotlib qt`**

&

**use** additional `matplotlib` calls as you expect 'em to modify/update the **`figure`** object

( I love using this both during prototyping phases & for interactive 3D-viewing of complex data visualisations (which I heavily miss in notebook's "*inline*"s) )
[image: 3D-view by matplotlib]
**BTW**: do you have about any methodology, which would allow to store a `matplotlib` 3D-view plot, as a complete, state-full container, that can be sent to some other user for her/his "load" and UI-interactive review? Would be great to hear about any such working :o)